# Where is the line for an acceptable question?

Tags: discussion

Take a look at this question: [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)

The question itself is very simple, and I have nothing against this question. I am just asking this because I don't want to put up any unacceptable questions on stackoverflow.  I am wondering why this question was not downvoted due to "lack of research" or "lack of effort in formatting the question." To me, it seems like a "please give me the answer" kind of question, which do receive a lot of downvotes and get closed on stackoverflow. And there are a lot of other examples of questions like this that have received many upvotes/stayed open.

Where is the line between a question that is acceptable and a question that is unacceptable?

Comment: That is an older question. Our standards have changed since then, but it's still a good reference question.

Comment: What is your proposed question?  We will critique it, fold, spindle and mutilate it.  If it survives, it's a good question.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi it's a fair point - presumably we are stomping out lots of other good reference questions because they don't "meet our standards."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Big O is a foundational programming concept.  A plain-English explanation on SO seems sensible.   Wikipedia can be very obtuse sometimes.

Questions that seem similar to this but get closed are, all too often, just someone who's too lazy to look it up himself.  Those are not hard to spot.

Questions that [do not demonstrate a good-faith effort at solving the problem themselves](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) do not do well.  These include questions that ask the community to solve the problem for them, and questions that can be easily answered by searching online.

Answer (score 1):

There are two completely different issues here.  There is the issue of whether or not a particular question should be open or closed.  That, while there can certainly be debate or discussion on the topic, is a question that should have an objective answer based on clear metrics.

Then there is the question of how to vote on a question.  That is entirely subjective, and entirely at the whim of each individual voter.  Anyone can decide whether to upvote or downvote a question for any reason they want (barring a few exceptions for voting fraud).  While there are a number of common reasons that people tend to up or down vote, thus allowing the potential of explaining the likely reason some posts are voted on as they were, at the end of the day nobody is bound to vote in a particular direction.  A vote can never, by definition, be *wrong*.  The result is that sometimes you can't explain the voting on a question; it can be inconsistent, confusing, unstable, etc.  You just need to learn to deal with that.